# how to show reviews on tabcontent?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

In my `magento details` page there is a `tabcontent`

[image]

When i clicking the **`review`**  **(see on fig)**  i want to show my reviews on the tab under **review**  of the particular product

Please help me to get a solution

Comment: suggest you do it with jquery

Comment: @Guerra which jquery please provide your valuable answer

Comment: need more details  but i'll supose some info and you adapt

Comment: @Guerra in my product detail page am add tabcontent by clicking the review tab i want show the reviews of that product

Comment: Oh, ok. My answer isn't about this. I don't understand the question at first. Sorry i'll edit it. You can do it with ajax. I'll need time to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<reference name="content">   
    <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
       <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
    </block> 
</reference>
```

under catalog.xml file

Use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>` to print your reviews in tabcontent

Answer (score 1):

Ok, forget all i said.
Lets assume you have:

```
<div id="review"></div>
```

And on this review you'll put the products review.
First you need a controller with one action to bring your products. I'll assume you know do this. So lets go just to ajax.

```
$('#review').live('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?= Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>/catalog/product/review', //lets assume you'r using ProductController the reviewAction().
        success: function(data) {
            $('#review').html(data);        
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There are errors in this markup. the "name" fields should be "id", and `$('$tab')` should be `$('#tab')`

Comment: @Guerra how i can do this without refreshing page?

Comment: With this code you can, ajax don't refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this free extension:
[Magento EasyTabs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-easytabs.html)

It covers all your needs (description, details, reviews...).